# Window options for shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, windows

The layout in our only bathroom is really cramped.  We are about to redo it and if we move the tub to a different wall it would open up a lot of space. The downside is that wall has the only window.  Removing the window isn't really an option. We like the light and it would degrade the curb appeal.

Googling hasn't turned up much.  What options exist to keep the window in the shower? We would prefer it be close to standard size and openable.

Comment: What makes you think there can't be a window next to a tub?  Is there a requirement in your area?

Comment: Is this a tub/shower combo and not just a tub that would have the window next to it? I assume the concern is having a window inside the wet shower area.

Comment: Glass deals with water fine, just ensure the edge sealing. I know of a shower made with clear glass outside on the side of a house - no-one overlooks it... But it has a fantastic view when showering...

Comment: My concern is with direct water on it. I said tub, but I probably should have full shower.  Am I being overly cautious with thinking that I would need to do something extra for a window which would have water spraying on it directly?